# OpenLayers version 5.3.0, problem on map export pdf

Tags: version, openlayers, export-to-pdf

I use openlayers version 5.3.0 and I want to export map pdf. The problem is that map extent on export isn't correct. It prints wrong height. At the openlayers (version 5.3.0) examples(https://openlayers.org/en/v5.3.0/examples/export-pdf.html?q=pdf) the result is the same as mine. The printed map height is more than map's extent. I checked also the same at the latest version (https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/export-pdf.html) and that is absolutely correct. It prints exactly the map extent. How can I fix it on my version without having to change version?

Thanks in advance.

```
// Reset original map size
map.setSize(size);
map.getView().fit(map.getView().calculateExtent(map.getSize()), {constrainResolution: false});
map.getView().setResolution(viewResolution);
document.body.style.cursor = 'auto';


// Set print size
let printSize = [width, height];
map.setSize(printSize);
let scaling = Math.min(width / size[0], height / size[1]);
map.getView().fit(map.getView().calculateExtent(map.getSize()), { size: printSize , constrainResolution: false});
map.getView().setResolution(viewResolution/scaling);
```

Comment: The new version calculates and sets the correct resolution instead of fitting to an the extent as fit doesn't work as expected with a rotated view - you could also do that with version 5.  A simple fix for versio 5 if the is no rotation in your view is using `map.getView().fit(extent, {size: printSize, constrainResolution: false})`; (also add `constrainResolution: false` to the reset).

Comment: @Mike Hello, thank you for your reply. I tried it but it still work inconsistently.

Comment: Avoid using both fit and setresolution as it might cause two rendercomplete events.  Here https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-gagarin-wqy6f?file=/main.js is the OpenLayers 6 example code with the canvas export part replaced by that use in the OpenLayers 5 example so it works with OL5.

Comment: @Mike, Hello, sorry for late response. I still have the same problem. I tried all this and nothing worked , I think that the problem is that I use web map with projection. Do you have any suggestion about this? Is there any way to calculate  correct  the resolution? Thank you in advance.